# vector inheritance, syntax error: missing ',' before '<'

Tags: inheritance, vector, syntax-error

While doing a project for my CS class, I ran into a bit of a problem while trying to inherit from the vector class. From everything I looked at, my syntax was correct, but it keeps throwing the error "syntax error: missing ',' before '<'" and no matter what I tweak in it, it doesn't seem to solve anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my "gVector.h" file.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class gVector : public vector<T> {
public:
gVector(int low, int high);

T& operator[](int i);

void resize(int lowIndex, int highIndex);

private:
    int lower;
    int upper;
};
#include "gVector.cpp"
```

Comment: If that's the sum total of your code, you need `std::vector`.

Comment: I had tried that before after reading through that post and it didn't work, but now it seems to have solved the problem. May be because of a few things I tweaked throughout my troubleshooting. Thank you for the help!